# Page not found Error in my Django Project

Tags: python, django, web, url

I just started learning Django and got the following error:

```
[![The site doesn't see URL and then Error 404][1]][1]
```

**urls.py - site**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('webexample/', include ('webexample.urls')),
]
```

**urls.py - webexample**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**views.py - webexample**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h3>This page isn't set up yet...</h3>")
```

[Error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G9vy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change path to this to work for the current url.

```
path(r'', views.index, name='index')
```

Comment: are you hitting this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/webexample/ ? works for me.

Comment: even just clicked on this link and have the same error

Comment: strange it perfectly works for me. Is you server running?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
   path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
```

or

```
re_path(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
```

to know more about this, you can the django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/

Comment: anyway. in console i see “GET /webexample/ HTTP/1.1” 404 2085    Not found: /webexample/

Comment: if you have used the path that i provided than  type this in your url localhost:8000/webexample/index

Comment: if you are using re_path than  make sure to import re_path

Comment: is you admin page loading?

Comment: well, no, it doesn't

Comment: check this 'django.contrib.admin' and you app name in you setting.py  INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webexample',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: did you do you migrations

Comment: yes. just tried to recall , wrong. doesn’t change anything currently

Comment: idk what you did wrong here. You have not done much here so you can refer to Django doc and start fresh.

Comment: well, it corrected with web and not yt tutorial, and i have no idea what has been changed because see no difference...